# html2canvas only works on page load but will not work on a jquery on click

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am trying to get html2canvas to generate a screenshot of a div and its contents when a button is clicked, however this does not work, I always see the message "Document cloned, element located at 784,2174 with size 0x0 using computed rendering", this should be a size of 500x500

HOWEVER if I put the code just under the "jQuery(document).ready(function(){" and let it run on page load it works just fine?

working example on page load

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            
            var ImageDiv = document.getElementById("_header_left-15-6999");

console.log(ImageDiv);
                
                html2canvas(ImageDiv, {
                    allowTaint: true,
                    useCORS: true
                }).then(function (canvas) {
                    
                    document.getElementById("PreviewImage").appendChild(canvas);
                });
});
```

none working example with on click

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery("#cc-download").on('click', function (e) {
                
                e.preventDefault();

            
            var ImageDiv = document.getElementById("_header_left-15-6999"); // tried standard js and jquery

console.log(ImageDiv);
                
                html2canvas(ImageDiv, {
                    allowTaint: true,
                    useCORS: true
                }).then(function (canvas) {
                    
                    document.getElementById("PreviewImage").appendChild(canvas);

                });

                });
            });
```

The only difference is that the version working on page load is wrapped in a jquery on click event, and it will not work with anything other than on page load.

Nothing on the page changes after page load, it is even finding the div when clicked but it is reporting it as 0x0

when I view the output for console.log(ImageDiv); it shows the exact div and elements inside that it should on both versions, but for some reason the on click version still sees it as 0x0

I have tried countless versions of this scouring countless examples and I just cannot get this to work with a jquery on click even, only working on page load.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to find out why?

site is using wordpress if that helps, even though I doubt it matters.

Thank you all in advance.

Kind regards

Wayne

**UPDATE**

As per requested from Konrad here is what is in the console

After page load this is in the console

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
/escoot/card-creator/#cc-download:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

and this is what is in after the click

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
/escoot/card-creator/#cc-download:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20 #1 0ms Starting document clone with size 1600x495 scrolled to 0,-777
html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
fn.toIFrame @ html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20
(anonymous) @ html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20
(anonymous) @ html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20
(anonymous) @ html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20
(anonymous) @ html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20
a @ html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20
Js @ html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20
(anonymous) @ html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20
element_to_png @ (index):181
(anonymous) @ (index):176
dispatch @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2
y.handle @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2 [Violation] 'click' handler took 230ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 32ms
html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20 #1 3352ms Document cloned, element located at 784,1751 with size 0x0 using computed rendering
html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20 #1 3352ms Starting DOM parsing
html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20 #1 3357ms Added image https://www.genbuz.com/escoot/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/card-500x500-wine-grad-1.jpg
html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20 #1 3362ms Starting renderer for element at 784,1751 with size 0x0
html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20 #1 3362ms Canvas renderer initialized (0x0) with scale 1
html2canvas.min.js?ver=6.1:20 #1 3680ms Finished rendering
```

I would also like to add that the div in question is a sticky div, so I am thinking that could be the reason?

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Any errors in the console after clicking?

Comment: @Konrad I will add the data to the question, to long for a comment, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that after a lot of trial and error I figured out it was the chrome extension hoverify that was causing the issues, disabled all extensions and then added them one by one, finally found the cause.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Kind regards

Wayne